# How to create a template file for org-capture in Spacemacs?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

I use a template file to capture a list of books. However last night, after wipe my old installation of spacemacs, when i try to capture a new book, it was impossible. I saw in capture buffer "Invalide Capture Template"

My org-capture-templates configuration is:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("r" ; touche pour rentrer une référence
         "Réference livre" ; on indique que l'on rentre la référence du livre
         entry (file+datetree+prompt "~/git/org/Liste_Livres.org") ; On sauve la référence dans le fichier associé.
         file "~/git/org/tpl-Liste-Livres.org" ) ; on utilise le template associé au fichier
         ("l" ; touche pour ajouter une entrée du lycée
         "Journal Lycée" ; on indique que l'on rentre la référence du livre
         entry (file+datetree "~/git/org/Journal_Lycee.org" ) ; On sauve l'entrée du journal dans le fichier associé.
         "* %? %^g") ; on utilise le template pour la note à ajouter
         ("n" ; touche pour ajouter une note
          "Notes" ; on indique que l'on rentre la référence du livre
          entry (file "~/git/org/Notes.org" ) ; On sauve la note dans le fichier associé.
          "* %? %t %^g \n :PROPERTIES:\n :LIEN:  %i  %a \n :END:") ; on utilise le template pour la note à ajouter
         )
)
```

My tpl-Liste-Livres.org is:

```
* Titre  :tags:                                                                                                                                                               

:PROPERTIES:
:Titre: 
:Auteur: 
:Pages: 
:Editeur: 
:Type: 
:Sujet: 
:Résumé: 
:Prets: 
:Lien: 
:Lu: 
:Acheté: 
:ISBN: 
:END:
```

I use emacs 25.1.1 from debian stable and spacemacs 0.300 develop

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your targets are out of date with the newest version of org-mode. `file+datetree` is deprecated, and has been replaced with `file+olp+datetree` with some new properties to control the datetree type and prompt options. Current templates are [documented here](https://orgmode.org/manual/Template-elements.html)

(Note also that your reference book target `file+datetree+prompt` is also out of date, and would need to be replaced with the `file+olp+datetree` target, and the new `:time-prompt` property.)